# Cygwin compilation error in ffmpeg: gcc is unable to create an executable file

Tags: windows, android, ffmpeg, cygwin

While i am executing the below command in cygwin in ffmpeg source directory
./build_android.sh

Here is the for [ffmpeg in android](http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-for-android/)

I am getting this error message

```
C:/cygwin64/home/SureshKumar/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc is unable to create an executable file. C compiler test failed.
```

Here is the build_android.sh code

```
#!/bin/bash

NDK=C:/cygwin64/home/SureshKumar/android-ndk-r10d
SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/
TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows-x86_64
function build_one
{
    ./configure \
    --prefix=$PREFIX \
    --enable-shared \
    --disable-static \
    --disable-doc \
    --disable-ffmpeg \
    --disable-ffplay \
    --disable-ffprobe \
    --disable-ffserver \
    --disable-avdevice \
    --disable-doc \
    --disable-symver \
    --cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
    --target-os=linux \
    --arch=arm \
    --enable-cross-compile \
    --sysroot=$SYSROOT \
    --extra-cflags="-Os -fpic $ADDI_CFLAGS" \
    --extra-ldflags="$ADDI_LDFLAGS" \
    $ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG
    make clean
    make
    make install
}
CPU=arm
PREFIX=basanth/android/$CPU 
ADDI_CFLAGS="-marm"
build_one
```

Looking forward for the answer.

Comment: Forget about `ffmpeg`. Can you compile a simple C executable?

Comment: Faheem, I was able to compile hello world sample. It got exe file.

Comment: So, does it execute correctly? In any case, please post a complete log of the build.

Comment: here mine log `WARNING: Unknown C compiler gcc, unable to select optimal CFLAGS
check_ld cc
check_cc
BEGIN /tmp/ffconf.BZtQUNs1.c
    1 int main(void){ return 0; }
END /tmp/ffconf.BZtQUNs1.c
gcc -c -o /tmp/ffconf.mimBKPkU.o /tmp/ffconf.BZtQUNs1.c
ffmpeg-3.2/configure: line 874: gcc: command not found
C compiler test failed.`